# C++ Web Framework w/ Embedded Server?

Tags: c++, web-frameworks, viewengine, embeddedwebserver, cppcms

I have been looking for a C++ Web Framework that would allow me to build a GUI Control Panel directly into a .dll plugin. In the past I have used Nancy Framework for .NET Projects which was exceptional (was my first time with this type of framework). I have found some good candidates based off of other Stack Overflow questions, however I am having trouble figuring out which, if any, have embedded web servers.

[C++ Server Pages](http://www.micronovae.com/CSP.html) - This Looked Exceptional, but runs off of IIS or Apache.

[CppCMS](http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/main) - Constantly recommended, but does it have an embedded server?

[TreeFrog](http://www.treefrogframework.org/) - Also recommended, but seems to have very broken documentation?

Which one of these would be recommended for a completely embedded solution? Ease of use would also be a huge plus, but I am willing to take the time to get it working provided it does what is needed. Thanks!

Comment: What's the license of treefrog? I couldn't find this info in the treefrog web site.

Comment: No clue, their site sucks pretty bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cppcms has an embedded server and is very well supported in embedded solutions. The documentation is complete and the support is very good, so perchance the documentation is not enough, the developer is certain to help you through your problems.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget about [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/). It also comes with a built-in web server.

Answer (score 0):

Both CppCMS and TreeFrog have a built-in web server.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at [ffead-cpp](http://code.google.com/p/ffead-cpp), it has an embedded web server, apache module, host of features and can run on Windows-Cygwin/BSD/Linux/Solaris